# Show an instance of a component class in main form in c#

Tags: c#, class, components, instance

If I add a component class to my project containing some common controls, how can I display an instance of it in a panel in my main form?

I use this to create an instance of my class:
Component test = new Component1(); 
where Component1 is the name of my Component class

Then how could I do something like:
panel1.Controls.Add(test); ?
Or is there a way to do this without using Panels?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to display Components on a form unless they are also Controls.

Comment: You're using the word 'component' - does that mean you have a class inheriting from the `System.Component` class? You need to inherit from `Control`, or from another class that derives from `Control`, to make a control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong class.  A Component cannot be a child of a panel or a form, it doesn't have a visual presentation.  The missing Handle property is the important one.

You need a Control.  Derive your class directly from Control or from one of the built-in control classes (Button, Label, etc).  You'd do the latter if you want to customize their behavior and make it re-usable.

Comment: Thank you, I see where my mistake was. But if I use a CustomControl class which is of type Control, I still can’t make it visible using panel1.Controls.Add(test). Is there some other command I should add? Or is there a easier way to display it in the main form?

Comment: There are not a lot of obvious failure modes.  Having a large Location, having a zero Size, not using BackColor or implementing Paint to make it distinct from the panel's background.

Answer (score 0):

> Then how could I do something like: panel1.Controls.Add(test); ?

This is the correct way.

> Or is there a way to do this without using Panels?

You could add your control to something other than a panel; for instance, to the form itself: `Controls.Add(test)`.